# Why '$pull' does not work in cherrypy

Tags: python, mongodb, cherrypy

I used `$pull` for removing a field in embedded document in mongodb. i used cherrypy to implemet this. this is my code.

```
models.login_info.update({},{$pull:{location:{time:date}}})
```

but while i run this code it gives me lexical error as follows.

`Lexical error at line 48, column 39.  Encountered: "$" (36), after : ""`

in the terminal i get the following error notification

`models.login_info.update({},{$pull:{location:{time:date}}})
                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: In python, you must use strings if the keys are strings (unlike javascript, where it doesn't have to be explicit) and the $ symbol is syntactically invalid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap `$pull` in quotes:

```
'$pull': {...
```